# Javascript - Loop string until null character found

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate through a string until a null character is found (\0), like how we do in C language. I have listed down the steps which I have tried below.

```
let exampleValue = 'abcdef';
let i = 0;

// Trial 1
while (exampleValue[i] !== '\0') {
  i++;
  // This seems to go on infinitely
}

// Trial 2
while (exampleValue[i] !== '\0'.charCodeAt(0)) {
  i++;
  // This seems to go on infinitely
}

// Trial 3
while (exampleValue[i] !== \0) {
  i++;
  // This throws an invalid character error
}

// Trial 4
while (exampleValue[i] !== undefined) {
  i++;
  // This seems to work
}
```

Based on the above samples, Trial 4 seems to work. Can I continue using Trial 4 for my desired output or is there a better way to solve my problem?

EDIT:
I apologize for not specifying my problem, I want to print each letter of the string by iterating through it without using exampleValue.length

EDIT 2:
After I read tadman's comment, I got to know Javascript's do not terminate their string using a null character but instead it stores it's keeps track of it characters and stores the length seperately.

Comment: Hint: C strings are NUL terminated. JavaScript ones are not.

Comment: "is there a better way to solve my problem?" That depends on what exactly your problem is. Iterating through a string is a means, not an end.

Comment: This very much feels like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Can you clarify what your larger goal is?

Comment: The reason you're getting `undefined` is because you're walking off the end of the string, so there's nothing to return. If you're used to C where it just keeps going and accessing invalid memory, that's not the case here.

Comment: @tadman Thank you, I never knew this. You solved my problem. I was too bland in specifying my problem. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count the length then just do `exampleValue.length`

```js
let exampleValue = 'abcdef';
let i = exampleValue.length;
console.log(i);
```

Or if you want to perform some logic using that char, you can try:

```js
let exampleValue = 'abcdef';
let i = 0;

exampleValue.split('').forEach(c => {
    console.log(c);
    i++;
    // Your logic here.
});

console.log(i);
```

Or using plain `for loop`:

```js
let exampleValue = 'abcdef';
let i = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < exampleValue.length; x++) {
  console.log(exampleValue.charAt(i));
  i++;
  // Your logic here.
}

console.log(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these cases because you will never get an `'\0'` in your string so the loop will run infinitely.

And the last case is working fine because after the last character of your string, the next character will be undefined.

Now, if you want to loop through the string then you can do it this way:

```js
let exampleValue = 'abcdef';
  let i = 0;
    
  while (i < exampleValue.length ) {
    console.log(exampleValue[i]);
    i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say exactly what you realy want... If you want to print the individual characters,

```
let exampleValue = 'abcdef';
for(var j = 0; j < exampleValue.length; j++){
    console.log(exampleValue[j]);
}
```

And if you are just interested in the number of elements:

```
int i = exampleValue.length;
console.log(i)
```